# Get JSONP with raw JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, get, jsonp

I want to read the JSONP data from an external domain in raw JavaScript (no jQuery).
So let's say https://www.domain.com/abc.php?foo=bar
contains: `{"error":false,"data_a":"abcabc","data_b":"123-456"}`

I couldn't really find much about this on google. But if I understood it correctly it should work about like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script>
    script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "https://www.domain.com/abc.php?foo=bar&callback=DataCallback";
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    function DataCallback(data) {
        for (var key in data) {
            var value = data[key];
            alert(key+' = '+value);
        }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't get an error, but I also don't get any alerts popping up.

Btw, I noticed that
https://www.domain.com/abc.php?foo=bar
and
https://www.domain.com/abc.php?foo=bar&callback=DataCallback
both show `{"error":false,"data_a":"abcabc","data_b":"123-456"}` in the browser.
Could that be the problem? Because I thought that the second link should show:
`DataCallback({"error":false,"data_a":"abcabc","data_b":"123-456"})`
?

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.

---

*You are never sending the request*

You have to add the script element to the document before it will be executed.

```
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

(Don't try doing that before the body exists or before you have defined your callback function)

---

*The server is not responding with JSONP*

You can't process plain JSON as if it were JSONP. The server is responding with JSON (well, when I try it, it responds with an advert for buying domains … perhaps you meant `example.com`?)

Answer (score 0):

I have complete pure javascript jsonp example...

You can have a look if you want

https://github.com/toosha01/ajax-javascript

Comment: Please add this as comment.